flutter how to stop StreamBuilder refresh when push to next page
In page A I use StreamBuilder to render some data,
then I push to B page using Navigator.push (A's Stream is not stoped)
I found A's StreamBuilder builder is still calling.

/// a complex model with lots of data
class AModel {}

class APage extends StatefulWidget {
  const APage({super.key});

  @override
  State<APage> createState() => _APageState();
}

class _APageState extends State<APage> {
  /// Data is pushed via websocket every second
  StreamController<List<AModel>> streamController =
      StreamController<List<AModel>>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: streamController.stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            print('This builder not stop after push to B Page');
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return const SizedBox.shrink();
            }
            final List<AModel> list = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ACell(model: list[index]);
              },
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class ACell extends StatelessWidget {
  final AModel model;
  const ACell({super.key, required this.model});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// AModel has a complex layout. Here we use a button as an example.
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
        );
      },
      child: const Text('Push'),
    );
  }
}

class BRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const BRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('B Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Questions：

After pushing to page B, the data of A is still refreshing. Does this have any impact on performance?
If so, do I have to turn A's Stream off manually when pushing to B?
Flutter doesn’t have a method like ViewDisappear, so how can I stop the stream?
Is there any better way？

Thank you very much!

You likely need to cancel the stream explicitly, but it's hard to be certain without seeing a minimal repro. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

It would be helpful if you consider giving some context. It gonna impact the performance ofc but whether that performance drop is negligible depends heavily on how often the StreamBuilder rebuilds and what you rebuild.
